Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nodeName') for VUE more 3.2.x
I upgraded from VUE 3.2.47 to 3.4.25 and had a problem. Moreover, all you need to do is change the VUE version. I use
    "highcharts": "^11.3.0",
    "highcharts-more": "^0.1.7",
    "highcharts-vue": "^1.4.3"

I tried to upgrade to the versions
    "highcharts": "^11.4.1",
    "highcharts-more": "^0.1.7",
    "highcharts-vue": "^2.0.1"

The result is the same. The v-if recommendations don't work. When returning to the old version of VUE 3.2.47, everything works great.
<highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>

I upgraded the highcharts version - I thought it would help. But it didn't help.

Leaping from highcharts-vue 1 to 2 might introduce breaking changes. vue also maybe have some. Time to go reach the changelogs of both packages to see if you have an issue there. Otherwise, a [repro] might also be the way.

Since highcharts-vue@2.0.0, the package requires usage of Vue >= 3.0.0. If you want to use older versions of vue, you should revert to older versions of highcharts-vue < 2.0.0: Highcharts Vue integration GitHub repository

OP is already using Vue3.
